# Syntactical error with csvsql query?

Tags: mysql, csv, csvkit

I have a csv file `attributes.csv` from which I want to retrieve all records to a new file `attributes_withoutPIDate.csv` excluding records for which the `Name` column has "PI Date" as the value.

Commanding `csvsql` in this manner

```
csvsql -d ',' -I --query 'select * where Name <> "PI Date" from attributes' attributes.csv > attributes_withoutPIDate.csv
```

yields an error

```
(sqlite3.OperationalError) near "from": syntax error
[SQL: select * where Name <> "PI Date" from attributes]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I suspect a syntactical error.  Can someone advise how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
csvsql -d ',' -I --query 'select * from attributes where Name <> "PI Date"' attributes.csv > attributes_withoutPIDate.csv
```

I think I've figured it out:-

The `from TABLE`
must precede `WHERE` clause.

When re-writing the query as such, it seems to work.

Comment: Yes, your SQL query was syntactically incorrect.